# activating asciidoctor diagram extension plantuml in maven pom.xml

Tags: asciidoctor

I use asciidoctor and maven with the asciidcotor-maven-plugin
I use asciidoctorJ and asciidoctorJ-diagramm

Now i have in my src-code of the document to render

`plantuml::input.puml[]`

with mvn -X compile I get now information in the console :-(

In the generated document I see the line of the src identically iaw ***not rendered at all***.

What is the problem?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.admvpl}</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jrcm}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.adjpdf}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>**asciidoctorj-diagram<**/artifactId>
                    <version>${version.addia}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

do I have to add something like

```
            <configuration>
                <requires>
                    <require>asciidoctor-diagramm</require>
                </requires>
            </configuration>
```

In the internet I only find configurations with gradle and gems, but not with maven... the problem is in backend HTML and PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find a fully working example here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/asciidoctor-diagram-example

Yes, you have to add both the dependency to `asciidoctorj-diagram` and you have to specify the requires/require in the configuration like you did in your question.